# Trouble with knife cookbook site install

Tags: chef-infra

It's alright when I download the cookbook.

```
PS> knife cookbook site download java_se
Downloading java_se from Supermarket at version 8.121.0 to D:/tools/chef-setupDevEnv/java_se-8.121.0.tar.gz
Cookbook saved: D:/tools/chef-setupDevEnv/java_se-8.121.0.tar.gz
```

However,when I want to install the cookbook the trouble came out.

```
PS>knife cookbook site install java_se
Installing java_se to D:/tools/chef-setupDevEnv/chef-java_se
ERROR: The cookbook repo path D:/tools/chef-setupDevEnv/chef-java_se does not exist or is not a directory
```

I found on the [chef blog](https://blog.chef.io/2015/03/16/using-chef-supermarket-a-guided-tour/),

> NOTE: If you receive the error “ERROR: IOError: Cannot open or read /Users/nshamrell/chef-repo/cookbooks/mysql/metadata.rb”, check which version of knife you are using with:
>   `$ knife -v`
>   If it is lower than Chef: 12.0.2, you will need to update your version of Knife. However, if you are using Chef DK and rvm, try running this command:
>   `$ rvm use system`

As my situation.

```
PS> knife -v
Chef: 12.19.36
PS>rvm use system
+ rvm use system
+ ~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (rvm:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

When I run this on git bash

```
$ rvm use system
bash: rvm: command not found
```

Does that mean I need to install rvm?However,I'm working on an windows workstation that's also the reason I chose chef.
What could the better solution now?

My knife.rb is in `D:\tools\chef-setupDevEnv\.chef`

```
current_dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)
log_level                :info
log_location             STDOUT
node_name                "bro****ane"
client_key               "#{current_dir}/bro****ane.pem"
chef_server_url          "https://api.chef.io/organizations/tm****gy"
cookbook_path            ["#{current_dir}/../chef-java_se"]
```

Comment: May be `D:/tools/chef-setupDevEnv/chef-java_se` is a file on your system?

Comment: Can you add your knife.rb please ? specially the cookbook_path variable

Comment: @DracoAter I don't have that file.Do I need to make that dir manually?

Comment: No, I don't think so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run a `knife cookbook site download` you tell knife to download a `.tar.gz` of the cookbook in the current directory where you are invoking it. In this case it works for you.

However a `knife cookbook site install` works differently. It assumes you have your `knife.rb` value `cookbook_path` pointing out to a directory in your filesystem which is a chef (and git) repo with (at least) one commit done. Which is **not** your case as far as I can see in what you're writing here.

You are invoking `knife` in `D:/tools/chef-setupDevEnv/SomeDirectory` while your `knife.rb` tells knife to go `#{current_dir}/../chef-java_se` which is `D:/tools/chef-setupDevEnv/chef-java_se`, which probably does not exist and if so, it is not a chef/git repo satisfying the condition I stated in the previous paragraph.

The main usage of `install` versus `download` is to have control with branches of changes in the cookbooks you use, you will find more information about its advantages [here](https://docs.chef.io/knife_cookbook_site.html#install).